# ConTeXt: Block array with labelled columns

Tags: matrices, context

I would like to display a matrix surrounded by square brackets that has row and column labels outside the square brackets. In LaTeX, I would use `blockarray` like the following:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{blockarray}{rcc}
      & C1 & C2 \\
  \begin{block}{r[cc]}
    R1 & -1 &  0 \\
    R2 & -1 &  0 \\
  \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image: Result with blockarray]

I've been able to reproduce something similar in ConTeXt using block matrices, but I can't figure out how to go one step further and align two columns across different blocks:

```
\starttext

\definemathmatrix[smatrix][left={\left[}, right={\right]}]
\definemathmatrix[omatrix][left={\phantom{[}}, right={\phantom{]}}]

\startformula
\startmatrix
\NC 
\NC 
    \startomatrix[n=2] 
        \NC C1 \NC C2 \NR 
    \stopomatrix
\NR

\NC 
    \startmatrix[n=1] 
        \NC R1 \NR 
        \NC R2 \NR 
    \stopmatrix
\NC
\NC % Need an extra \NC, might be a bug
    \startsmatrix[n=2] 
        \NC -1 \NC 0 \NR
        \NC -1 \NC 0 \NR
    \stopsmatrix
\NR
\stopmatrix
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

With the result:

[image: Result with matrix]

It's actually not too bad, but the column labels are not aligned with the actual columns and this becomes more obvious with more complex column values.

I can hack together alignment using `phantom` elements, but is there a more general method to get column labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this with the `bbordermatrix` environment which produces the same result as the normal `bordermatrix` environment but replaces the braces with brackets.

```
\starttext

\startformula
    \startbbordermatrix
    \NC    \NC C1 \NC C2 \NR
    \NC R1 \NC -1 \NC 0  \NR
    \NC R2 \NC -1 \NC 0  \NR
    \stopbbordermatrix
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image: Bordermatrix with brackets]

Comment: My ConTeXt installation seems to be out of date as `bbordermatrix` can't be found. However, I was able to find a similar definition here: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/089694.html

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer by Metafox, for those with older installations of ConTeXt, it seems like `bbordermatrix` was also defined by Hans Hagen on the mailing list. The source can be found here: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/089694.html.

For the sake of convenience, here is a copy:

```
\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\math_border_matrix#1#2#3% adapted plain
   {\begingroup
    %
    \pushmacro\cr
    %
    \setbox\scratchbox\hbox\bgroup
      \mr B%
    \egroup
    \scratchdimenone\wd\scratchbox
    %
    \scratchdimentwo.2\bodyfontsize
    %
    \mathsurround\zeropoint
    %
    \setbox\scratchboxone\vbox\bgroup
      \def\cr{%
        \crcr
        \noalign\bgroup
          \kern\scratchdimentwo
          \global\let\cr\endline
        \egroup
      }%
      \ialign{%
        \startimath\alignmark\alignmark\stopimath
        \hfil
        \kern\dimexpr\scratchdimentwo+\scratchdimenone\relax
        \aligntab
        \thinspace
        \hfil
        \startimath\alignmark\alignmark\stopimath
        \hfil
        \aligntab
        \aligntab
        \quad
        \hfil
        \startimath\alignmark\alignmark\stopimath
        \hfil
        \crcr
        \omit
        \strut
        \hfil
        \crcr
        \noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}%
        #3\crcr
        \omit
        \strut
        \cr
      }%
    \egroup
    \setbox\scratchboxtwo\vbox\bgroup
      \unvcopy\scratchboxone
      \global\setbox\globalscratchbox\lastbox
    \egroup
    \setbox\scratchboxtwo\hbox\bgroup
      \unhbox\globalscratchbox
      \unskip
      \global\setbox\globalscratchbox\lastbox
    \egroup
    \setbox\scratchboxtwo\hbox\bgroup
      \startimath
      \kern\dimexpr\wd\globalscratchbox-\scratchdimenone\relax
      \left#1\relax
      \kern-\wd\globalscratchbox
      \global\setbox\globalscratchbox\vbox\bgroup
        \box\globalscratchbox
        \kern\scratchdimentwo
      \egroup
      \vcenter\bgroup
        \kern-\ht\globalscratchbox
        \unvbox\scratchboxone
        \kern-\baselineskip
      \egroup
      \thinspace
      \right#2\relax
      \stopimath
    \egroup
    \null
    \thickspace
    \vbox\bgroup
      \kern\ht\globalscratchbox
      \box\scratchboxtwo
    \egroup
    %
    \popmacro\cr
    %
    \endgroup}

\unexpanded\def\bordermatrix {\math_border_matrix()}
\unexpanded\def\bbordermatrix{\math_border_matrix[]}

\protect

\starttext

A plain border matrix:

\startformula
\bordermatrix{
    a & b & c & d \cr
    e & f & G & h \cr
    i & j & k & l \cr}
\stopformula

\startformula
\bbordermatrix{
    a & b & c & d \cr
    e & f & G & h \cr
    i & j & k & l \cr}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```